# Fix issue on Perl script

Tags: perl, devops, system-administration

I have a script to read the log file and search all 41 step if it shows status "--BuildSuccessful--",  the log file will move from folder current to successful. It worked but recently, sometimes it was not working correctly. I don't understand what are going on, the log file still on folder current. Please take your time to help me improve my code.

Here log file template:

```
Build Number::  21.9004.5200.0  BUILT TYPE::     Nightly build
===========================================================
Progress                Time                Build Step
BuildStarted CosmoRR        Tue Apr 11 20:05:38 2017        0
CheckChanges            Tue Apr 11 20:05:38 2017            0
PreBuildToolsSLN        Tue Apr 11 20:14:07 2017        0
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:14:12 2017        0
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:14:12 2017        0
ReplaceUCBVersionNumber Tue Apr 11 20:14:27 2017    1
BuildVPresent           Tue Apr 11 20:14:27 2017            2
BuildFlashAndFlex       Tue Apr 11 20:14:35 2017        3
BuildFlexTop            Tue Apr 11 20:15:00 2017            4
ObfuscatePHP            Tue Apr 11 20:15:07 2017            5
ReplaceSTVersionNumber      Tue Apr 11 20:15:11 2017        6
RunGetEnums         Tue Apr 11 20:15:11 2017            7
ReplaceClientVersionNum Tue Apr 11 20:15:11 2017    8
BuildAllSLN         Tue Apr 11 20:15:11 2017            9
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017        9
BuildSolution           Tue Apr 11 20:35:32 2017            10
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 20:43:20 2017        10
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 20:43:20 2017        10
BuildPresenterInstaller Tue Apr 11 20:43:20 2017    11
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 20:43:20 2017        11
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 20:43:23 2017        11
BuildAcceleratorInstaller   Tue Apr 11 20:43:23 2017    11
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 20:43:23 2017        11
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 20:43:24 2017        11
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 20:44:24 2017        11
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 20:44:24 2017        11
GetPhoneInstaller       Tue Apr 11 20:44:24 2017        12
GetManhattanClientExo       Tue Apr 11 20:44:28 2017        13
GetManhattanClientEndo      Tue Apr 11 20:44:29 2017        14
GetManhattanClient      Tue Apr 11 20:44:29 2017        15
GetShoreTelPlayer       Tue Apr 11 20:44:34 2017        16
GetConnectforMSFT       Tue Apr 11 20:44:35 2017        17
GetCCClient         Tue Apr 11 20:44:37 2017            18
SpawnLinuxBuild     Tue Apr 11 20:44:38 2017        19
BuildSwitches           Tue Apr 11 20:44:39 2017            20
BuildFilesys            Tue Apr 11 21:07:07 2017            20
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 21:07:13 2017        20
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 21:07:13 2017        20
BuildCASTestingTools        Tue Apr 11 21:07:17 2017        21
ReportDevEnvErrs        Tue Apr 11 21:07:33 2017        21
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 21:07:33 2017        21
BuildPHR            Tue Apr 11 21:07:33 2017            22
BuildRuby           Tue Apr 11 21:07:36 2017            23
BuildRubyDirector2      Tue Apr 11 21:07:52 2017        24
CreateTAPISDK           Tue Apr 11 21:13:30 2017            25
SignTDIMedia            Tue Apr 11 21:13:31 2017            26
BuildAPPFolder          Tue Apr 11 21:13:32 2017            27
BuildRubywin            Tue Apr 11 21:13:40 2017            28
BuildRubymingw          Tue Apr 11 21:18:06 2017            29
BuildNginx          Tue Apr 11 21:22:05 2017            30
BuildNginx          Tue Apr 11 21:22:06 2017            31
GetSalesforcePlugin     Tue Apr 11 21:22:19 2017        32
RunPrep4Install     Tue Apr 11 21:22:23 2017        33
RunPrep4Install_iteration_1 Tue Apr 11 21:27:23 2017    33
RunPrep4Install_iteration_2 Tue Apr 11 21:32:23 2017    33
RunPrep4Install_iteration_3 Tue Apr 11 21:37:23 2017    33
RunPrep4Install_iteration_4 Tue Apr 11 21:42:23 2017    33
RunPrep4Install_iteration_5 Tue Apr 11 21:47:23 2017    33
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 21:47:48 2017        33
Client_3rdParty_DiagMonitoring_Installer    Tue Apr 11 21:47:48 2017    34
Build3rdPartyInstaller      Tue Apr 11 21:47:48 2017        34
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 21:47:48 2017        34
BuildDiagMonitoringInstaller    Tue Apr 11 21:47:50 2017    34
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 21:47:50 2017        34
BuildDMuiInstaller      Tue Apr 11 21:47:51 2017        34
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 21:47:51 2017        34
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 21:49:54 2017        34
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 21:49:54 2017        34
BuildRemoteServer       Tue Apr 11 21:49:54 2017        35
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 21:49:54 2017        35
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:01:25 2017        35
BuildRemoteServerDC     Tue Apr 11 22:01:25 2017        36
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:01:25 2017        36
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:08:12 2017        36
Server_LinuxDVX_Switch_Platform_DC_Installer    Tue Apr 11 22:08:12 2017    37
BuildDataCenterServerInstaller  Tue Apr 11 22:08:12 2017    37
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:08:12 2017        37
BuildLinuxDVSInstaller      Tue Apr 11 22:08:14 2017        37
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:08:14 2017        37
BuildSwitchInstaller        Tue Apr 11 22:08:14 2017        37
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:08:14 2017        37
BuildPlatformInstaller      Tue Apr 11 22:13:15 2017        37
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:13:15 2017        37
BuildServerInstaller        Tue Apr 11 22:13:15 2017        37
BuildMsiInstaller       Tue Apr 11 22:13:15 2017        37
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:59:44 2017        37
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:59:46 2017        37
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:59:46 2017        37
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:59:47 2017        37
CheckSignCodeErrors     Tue Apr 11 22:59:47 2017        37
RunpostInstall          Tue Apr 11 22:59:47 2017            38
ReportVersions          Tue Apr 11 23:00:03 2017            39
BuildAllSims            Tue Apr 11 23:00:04 2017            40
ReportSIMDevEnvErrors       Tue Apr 11 23:02:41 2017        40
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 23:02:41 2017        40
BuildAllSimsVS2010      Tue Apr 11 23:03:44 2017        41
ReportSIMDevEnvErrors       Tue Apr 11 23:03:57 2017        41
CheckDevenvErrs     Tue Apr 11 23:03:57 2017        41
===========================================================
--BuildSuccessful--
Successful          Tue Apr 11 23:05:55 2017            41
```

And my script:

```
opendir DIR1, "C:\\BuildStatus\\Current\\" or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @files=  grep ! /^\.+$/, readdir DIR1;
foreach my $files (@files) 
{ 
    $searchsucs = "--BuildSuccessful--";
    $oldLoc2 = "C:\\BuildStatus\\Current\\".$files;
    $newLocS2 = "C:\\BuildStatus\\History\\Successful\\".$files;
    $newLocF2 = "C:\\BuildStatus\\History\\Failed\\".$files;
    open(E_FILE,"C:\\BuildStatus\\Current\\".$files);
    @valf2 = <E_FILE>;
    my $newLoc2 = "";
    foreach $searchf2 (@valf2)
    {
        if ($searchf2=~/$searchsucs/)
            { print "matched";
                $num1 =$num1 + 1;
            }else
            { print "not matched";
                $num1 = $num1 + 0;
            }
    }
    close E_FILE;
    print "moving build status file......\n";
    if($num1 == 1) {
      fmove($oldLoc2, $newLocS2) or warn "$file Warning: Not able to move build status files \n ";
      system(qq(E:\\depot\\builds\\PassedBuilds.bat));
    } else {
      fmove($oldLoc2, $newLocF2) or warn "$file Warning: Not able to move build status files \n ";
    }
}
closedir DIR1;
```

Comment: Looks like you are reusing your `$num1` variable for each file, but you are not resetting it to `0`.  After the first successful build, the rest will hit your `else` block because `$num1 > 1`.

Comment: It means I must set $num1 = 0 before foreach loop???

Comment: The calculation of `$num1` is certainly problematic. But that's not causing this problem. No matter what value `$num1` has, the file should still be moved out of the current directory and into either the "Successful" or "Failed" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what is causing the problems that you are describing ("the log file still on folder current") but I can certainly help with the other part of your question ("help me improve my code"). I'd write this code something like this:

```
# Lexical variable for directory handle
# Single-quoted string
# Reverse slash direction to improve readability
opendir my $dir_h, 'C:/BuildStatus/Current/'
  or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";

my @files =  grep ! /^\.+$/, readdir $dir_h;

# This doesn't change. Move it out of the loop.
my $searchsucs = '--BuildSuccessful--';

# Rename $files to $file to improve readability
foreach my $files (@files) {
  # Lexical variables (with "my")
  # Use variable interpolation instead of string concatenation
  # Reverse slash durection for readability
  # Don't define variables until you need them
  my $oldLoc2  = "C:/BuildStatus/Current/$file";


  # Lexical variable for file-handle
  # Three args in open() call
  # Use $oldLoc2 variable
  # Check return value from open()
  open(my $fh, '<', $oldLoc2)
    or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

  # Use a $found variable
  my $found;

  # Remove unused $newLoc2 variable
  # Remove unnecessary @valf2 variable
  # Process input file a line at a time (use while, not foreach)
  # Use Perl's default variable $_ for clarity
  while (<$fh>) {
    if (/$searchsucs/) {
      print "matched";
      $found = 1;
      # Skip rest of loop
      last;
    } else {
      # This will be a bit noisy!
      print "not matched"
    }
  }

  # Lexical filehandle means no need to explicitly close file

  print "moving build status file......\n";

  # Simpler logic check
  if ($found) {
    my $newLocS2 = "C:/BuildStatus/History/Successful/$file";
    fmove($oldLoc2, $newLocS2)
      or warn "$file Warning: Not able to move build status files \n ";
    system(qq(E:\\depot\\builds\\PassedBuilds.bat));
  } else {
    my $newLocF2 = "C:/BuildStatus/History/Failed/$file";
    fmove($oldLoc2, $newLocF2)
      or warn "$file Warning: Not able to move build status files \n ";
  }
}
```

Does that help at all?